# Whats the latest service pack for sharepoint server 2010. SP2?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I would like to download the latest SP for Sharepoint server 2010. Is there a SP2?

Comment: There is SP1 & then CUs. No SP2 yet. Link by @Robban1980 has all details

Comment: I would recommend anyone considering installing Cumulative Updates to read the below article first. Microsoft has been known on more than one occasion to release regressive updates. Cumulative updates are a collection of Hotfixes and should only generally be deployed if your software is affected by a problem that the update fixes. Otherwise it is best to wait for the next available service pack. http://www.harbar.net/archive/2011/06/30/327.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all the updates for SharePoint 2010 here: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn789211%28v=office.14%29#BKMK_2010

There is an SP2.

Comment: Can I install the CU?Is it stable?

Comment: Microsoft wouldn't post them if they weren't stable. The latest CU displayed is http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2598354 for SharePoint Server 2010.

Answer (score 2):

SP2 has been release in August 2013. You can find it here for SP Server 2010

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2687453

Comment: Just downloaded SP2.  Keep in mind the release was updated because of issues.  So yes, MS will post problem CUs and SPs.  Link contains info... [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2013/07/23/sharepoint-server-2010-service-pack-2-has-been-released.aspx)

Comment: what should be the sql native client version for this SP 2010 SP2? my current sp version is SP 2010 WITH SERVICE PACK2 - KB2687453 and my sql server is Microsoft SQL Server Developer Edition (64-bit)
SQL Version Num : SQL Server- 10.50.1617 . i donno because of  some strange reason, am unable to create a search serv appln.,neither using powershell nor central admin UI. Am getting the error on eventviewer Could not access the Search database. A generic error occurred while trying to access the database to obtain the schema version info. am stuck with this